# Python Reading JSON as Binary

Tags: python, json, parsing, byte

I need to parse a file with JSONs in it. File format is txt and content is like below:

```
{"key_1":"value_1", ....., "key_n":"value_n"}
{"key_1":"value_1", ....., "key_n":"value_n"}
......
```

There is no association between JSONs they are just in the file consecutively. They also includes non-utf characters, so it is impossible to parse them with using json library. I tried to read them line by line in byte format. Then a line that read as like below:

```
b'{"key_1":"value_1", ....., "key_n":"value_n"}'
```

I'm stuck to that step. I read a line corresponds to a JSON but it includes non-utf characters and its format is byte. How can I convert it to a dictionary?

Comment: Could you give an example of one of the non-utf chars?

Comment: use `json` module to loads or dump the data.

Comment: Non-utf characters are like these: TÜRKÝYE ÝÞ BANKASI A.Þ.

Comment: There are no "non utf8 characters", there are "non utf8 encodings". Please provide some real simplified sample data.

Comment: When I tried to read line by line I'm getting this error:  'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 2981: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @Tolga Karahan, as @Thierry Lathuille mentioned, this means that the file isn't utf-8 encoded but those chars can definitely be represented in unicode.  You can usually use a text editor (e.g. Notepad++) to work out what the encoding is and then use something like `file = open(filename, encoding="latin-1")`.

Comment: First I tried it on Ubuntu. I have dual boot system. Then I tried it on Windows and problem was solved. Thanks.